# É possível converter um pseudocódigo para portugol?

Tags: portugol

Estou com problemas pra decifrar as `:←` e as parte;

```
Para cont ← 0 Até 12 Faça 
Leia Sexo
Leia Idade
    mGeral ← mGeral + Idade
     Se Sexo = “M” Então
      mHomem ← mHomem + Idade
       nHomem ← nHomem + 1
Senão
       mMulher ← mMulher + Idade
        nMulher ← nMulher + 1
Fim Se 
          cont ← cont+1 
Fim Para 
           mGeral ← mGeral / 12 
            mHomem ← mHomem / nHomem 
             mMulher ← mMulher / nMulher
```

---

```
Programa IdadeSexo
Var mGeral, mHomem, nHomem, mMulher, nMulher, Idade, cont: Inteiro 
Var Sexo: Texto 
Início 
mGeral ← 0 
mHomem ← 0 
mMulher ← 0 
Para cont ← 0 Até 12 Faça 
 Leia Sexo 
 Leia Idade 
 mGeral ← mGeral + Idade 
 Se Sexo = “M” Então 
 mHomem ← mHomem + Idade 
nHomem ← nHomem + 1 
 Senão 
mMulher ← mMulher + Idade 
nMulher ← nMulher + 1 
Fim Se 
 cont ← cont+1 
Fim Para 
mGeral ← mGeral / 12 
mHomem ← mHomem / nHomem 
mMulher ← mMulher / nMulher 
Escreva “A média de idade geral do grupo é: ” mGeral 
Escreva “A média de idade das Mulheres do grupo é: ” mMulher 
Escreva “A média de idade dos Homens do grupo é: ” mHomem 
FIM.
```

Comment: Por favor, formate a pergunta de forma legível.

Comment: Seus títulos vem sendo bem ruins... Use-os para fazer uma descrição do ***exato problema*** que você tem.

Comment: Dica: reserve um tempinho pra ler a [help], acho que você está perigosamente próximo [disto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)...

Answer (score 5):

`←` Significa sinal de atribuição, ele precisa ser trocado por `=`

pseudo código:

```
mGeral ← mGeral + Idade
```

em portugol vira:

```
mGeral = mGeral + Idade
```

Comment: a parte de texto que uso como var posso usar oque? como pra número eu uso para inteiro ou real.

Comment: O `var` não precisa segundo o help do portugol studio, fica apenas, `tipo nome_da_variavel` ex: `inteiro idade`